# Solving $ \int x^{\frac{-1}{x}} dx $

Tags: integration

I would like to solve this integration
$$ \int x^{\frac{-1}{x}} dx $$
I tried to solve it using integration by parts but I failed to complete it.

Comment: It probably does not have an elementary anti-derivative, but I'll check.

Comment: Yup. No elementary antiderivative. If you can find the Taylor series of $x^{\frac{-1}{x}}$, then you can integrate that.

Comment: Otherwise, it is impossible to compute that integral using any combination of standard techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clathratus already commented, forget about the antiderivative (this problem looks- at least to me - still worse than [the sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). You can also forget about a series expansion around $x=0$.

To provide you something, suppse that you are concerned by the definite integral
$$I=\int_1^a x^{-\frac{1}{x}}\, dx$$ Even if the series expansion is feasible around $x=1$
$$1-(x-1)+2 (x-1)^2-\frac{7}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{35}{6} (x-1)^4-\frac{113}{12}
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$ it would not be of any use for the integration.

However, the integrand could be approximated using a [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). To make it workable, let us consider the $[n,2]$ ones. They will write
$$\frac{1+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x-1)^k}{1+b_1(x-1)+b_2(x-1)^2}$$ and its integration will lead to some polynomial plus an arctangent plus a logarithm. For example, using $n=4$ we should get
$$\frac{1+\frac{203 }{110}(x-1)+\frac{929}{770} (x-1)^2+\frac{107}{770} (x-1)^3-\frac{101
   }{4620}(x-1)^4 }{1+\frac{313 }{110}(x-1)+\frac{158}{77} (x-1)^2 }$$ the integration of which not making any problem.

Let us try for a few values of $a$ and compare to the result of the numerical integration.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.0 & 0.00000 & 0.00000 \\
 1.5 & 0.42546 & 0.42546 \\
 2.0 & 0.79003 & 0.79006 \\
 2.5 & 1.13890 & 1.13920 \\
 3.0 & 1.48413 & 1.48548 \\
 3.5 & 1.82936 & 1.83346 \\
 4.0 & 2.17519 & 2.18497 \\
 4.5 & 2.52086 & 2.54070 \\
 5.0 & 2.86490 & 2.90087
\end{array}
\right)$$ Not fantastic, for sure !